# Changing vibration intensity for system on Lollipop?

Tags: haptic-feedback

Currently the vibration intensity in my Lollipop ROM is too high, even for things like haptic feedback. This is a problem with most ROMs on my device (Xiaomi Mi3W), and was fixed in 4.4 with an alteration to framework-res.apk [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!cRJl1J5Y!sYrjPEXgUt0IguXiRXhNeaqod2Cu4AsRPen88KkHidU), but I can find no information on what files were changed. The only this I can find is [here on xda-developers forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1796789), but this is for GB and neither the LP or KK framework-res have that xml file. I cannot replace the LP framework with the KK framework because I am guessing it will just cause bootloops/force closes.

Does anyone know of a system modification that be changed to lower system vibrations for everything? The modification can be in the source or compiled ROM.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Settings> Sound & notification> Other sounds> Vibrator intensity.

Comment: Many manufacturers modify Android to add their own settings, meaning that settings on your specific phone may be different or missing altogether on another.  "Vanilla" Android 5.0 does not have a "Vibrator intensity" setting under the options you mentioned.  Please make sure to mention your specific phone make and model when giving such answers.

Comment: Motorola is reputed to use a relatively vanilla Android, and version 6.0.1 on the Moto G4 does not have any vibration intensity settings.  It has only Other sounds -> Vibrate on touch: on or off.   I only hope Nougat will allow more customization.