# how to reduce vibration density in my htc one m8?

Tags: htc

whenever i have a message or incoming call my mobile upper speaker is making much vibration disturbance. I need to vibrate my phone but only to be normal?.It is making loud vibrations

Comment: Which Android version? If it is Android Lollipop, your question  may be considered a duplicate of  [Changing vibration intensity for system on Lollipop?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/95558)

Comment: android kitkat 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

If you are rooted you can install kernel adiutor (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.grarak.kerneladiutor). This has a direct setting in the miscellaneous tab for decreasing vibration intensity.

Without root, I'm afraid it is next to impossible. You can flash the regular supersu.zip, it should work fine. More details on rooting can be found at xda's website.